# Is there a way to detect the user's password entry in sshd to warn that they must change it?

Tags: linux, password, sshd

I have a box I would like to distribute as a Vagrant box (and eventually Dockerfile).  the initial password specified in the `README` file, I'd like to detect if it is being used (it's very simple and is 4 characters long) and warn the user on login that they need to change it.  Is this possible?  I don't see anything that hints this in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

An acceptable workaround if not would be reading the number of keystrokes and if 4 are detected warn the user that way.  A REALLY good feature would be to change the password if the user doesn't reply after 3 times.

(NOTE: I'm following a tip from a reviewer that this is a better place to post this question than stack overflow proper)

Comment: What if users log in using SSH keys?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of doing this complicated approach, you should set the users password to expired so they must change it on the next login.

From `man passwd`:

> -**e, --expire**
>
> Immediately expire an account's password. This in effect can force a user to change his/her password at the user's next login.

So to set the password of `user1` to expired, use

```
passwd -e user1
```

Comment: Thank you.  This rivals a silk evening gown for elegance.

Comment: And it happens to be what I told you to do in the comments to your deleted question on SO ;)